# How to type plain object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wanna type a plain object of JavaScript, and write this:

```
interface PlainObject {
  [k: string]: any;
}
```

But I found:

```
type A = keyof PlainObject // string | number

interface PlainArray {
  [k: number]: any;
}

type B = keyof PlainArray // number
```

Question 1: Why this happens?
Question 2: How can I type a plain object like `{ name: 'timi' }`

Comment: Here is the explanation in the Typescript handbook:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is by design, the `string` index will mean the object is indexable by a `string` or a `number`. The [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures) say it best:

> If you have a type with a string index signature, `keyof T` will be `string | number` (and not just string, since in JavaScript you can access an object property either by using strings (object['42']) or numbers (object[42])). And T[string] is just the type of the index signature.

There is no way to have a type for which `keyof` will return just `string`. (There is the `--keyofStringsOnly` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) but that is there mostly for backward compatibility and should not be enabled on new code)